# Convert Bitmap Files into JPEG using the GD library in PHP

Tags: php, bitmap, gd, jpeg

I have been trying to figure out a way to convert bitmap files into a JPEG using the GD library in PHP.

I have tried numerous implementations but nothing seems to work.  I have tried to tell my client that they should not use Bitmap files but he insists and quite frankly does not comprehend enough about computers to convert them to JPG on his own.

I can not use ImageMagick on this server and I need a pure GD solution.  Thank you in advance for any and all help.

**EDIT:**

The bitmap images that are being used are 16-bit and that is where the problem is occurring.

I have this function that I have working .... kinda:

```
function ImageCreateFromBMP($filename) {
    if (! $f1 = fopen($filename,"rb")) return FALSE;

    $FILE = unpack("vfile_type/Vfile_size/Vreserved/Vbitmap_offset", fread($f1,14));
    if ($FILE['file_type'] != 19778) return FALSE;

    $BMP = unpack('Vheader_size/Vwidth/Vheight/vplanes/vbits_per_pixel'.
        '/Vcompression/Vsize_bitmap/Vhoriz_resolution'.
        '/Vvert_resolution/Vcolors_used/Vcolors_important', fread($f1,40));
    $BMP['colors'] = pow(2,$BMP['bits_per_pixel']);

    if ($BMP['size_bitmap'] == 0) $BMP['size_bitmap'] = $FILE['file_size'] - $FILE['bitmap_offset'];
    $BMP['bytes_per_pixel'] = $BMP['bits_per_pixel']/8;
    $BMP['bytes_per_pixel2'] = ceil($BMP['bytes_per_pixel']);
    $BMP['decal'] = ($BMP['width']*$BMP['bytes_per_pixel']/4);
    $BMP['decal'] -= floor($BMP['width']*$BMP['bytes_per_pixel']/4);
    $BMP['decal'] = 4-(4*$BMP['decal']);
    if ($BMP['decal'] == 4) $BMP['decal'] = 0;

    $PALETTE = array();
    if ($BMP['colors'] < 16777216 && $BMP['colors'] != 65536) {
        $PALETTE = unpack('V'.$BMP['colors'], fread($f1,$BMP['colors']*4));
    }

    $IMG = fread($f1,$BMP['size_bitmap']);
    $VIDE = chr(0);

    $res = imagecreatetruecolor($BMP['width'],$BMP['height']);
    $P = 0;
    $Y = $BMP['height']-1;
    while ($Y >= 0) {
        $X=0;
        while ($X < $BMP['width']) {
            if ($BMP['bits_per_pixel'] == 24)
                $COLOR = unpack("V",substr($IMG,$P,3).$VIDE);
            elseif ($BMP['bits_per_pixel'] == 16) {
                $COLOR = unpack("v",substr($IMG,$P,2));
                $blue  = ($COLOR[1] & 0x001f) << 3;
                $green = ($COLOR[1] & 0x07e0) >> 3;
                $red   = ($COLOR[1] & 0xf800) >> 8;
                $COLOR[1] = $red * 65536 + $green * 256 + $blue;
            }
            elseif ($BMP['bits_per_pixel'] == 8) {
                $COLOR = unpack("n",$VIDE.substr($IMG,$P,1));
                $COLOR[1] = $PALETTE[$COLOR[1]+1];
            }
            elseif ($BMP['bits_per_pixel'] == 4) {
                $COLOR = unpack("n",$VIDE.substr($IMG,floor($P),1));
                if (($P*2)%2 == 0) $COLOR[1] = ($COLOR[1] >> 4) ; else $COLOR[1] = ($COLOR[1] & 0x0F);
                $COLOR[1] = $PALETTE[$COLOR[1]+1];
            }
            elseif ($BMP['bits_per_pixel'] == 1) {
                $COLOR = unpack("n",$VIDE.substr($IMG,floor($P),1));
                if     (($P*8)%8 == 0) $COLOR[1] =  $COLOR[1]        >>7;
                elseif (($P*8)%8 == 1) $COLOR[1] = ($COLOR[1] & 0x40)>>6;
                elseif (($P*8)%8 == 2) $COLOR[1] = ($COLOR[1] & 0x20)>>5;
                elseif (($P*8)%8 == 3) $COLOR[1] = ($COLOR[1] & 0x10)>>4;
                elseif (($P*8)%8 == 4) $COLOR[1] = ($COLOR[1] & 0x8)>>3;
                elseif (($P*8)%8 == 5) $COLOR[1] = ($COLOR[1] & 0x4)>>2;
                elseif (($P*8)%8 == 6) $COLOR[1] = ($COLOR[1] & 0x2)>>1;
                elseif (($P*8)%8 == 7) $COLOR[1] = ($COLOR[1] & 0x1);
                $COLOR[1] = $PALETTE[$COLOR[1]+1];
            }
            else
                return FALSE;

            imagesetpixel($res,$X,$Y,$COLOR[1]);

            $X++;
            $P += $BMP['bytes_per_pixel'];
        }
        $Y--;
        $P+=$BMP['decal'];
    }

    fclose($f1);
    return $res;
}
```

The resulting image is this:

[image: Uploaded Image]

If you look at the image on the left hand side you can see that the resulting image is not correctly lined up.  The little sliver belongs on the right hand side.  Where is the code going wrong?  The problem is occurring in the 16-bit else-if.

Thank you again for all the help.

Comment: Had a look at your code, seems correct. Are you sure that the BMP format is as expected (54 bytes, no palette data, image data following)? As this is some exotic BMP variant, there might be additional/less data in the header that leads to this "shifting" error.

Comment: I have to be honest I am not really sure what is going on with the image.  If there was a way to email one of the pictures to you so you could check it out... I am more interested now than ever in what is going on with these image files. An email I can be contacted at is dphoebus at g mail dot com and I will reply with one of the images.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use this function:

http://www.programmierer-forum.de/function-imagecreatefrombmp-welche-variante-laeuft-t143137.htm

It supports several bitrates like 16- and 32-bit. Plus it contains some bugfixes regarding missing filesize, negative color palettes, error output, additional 16-bit mask header (this was the main problem on 16-bit) and reduced color palette (biClrUsed).

Hope you like it ;)

Update in 2015: This function is now part of [DOMPDF](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/blob/master/src/Helpers.php) (Search on page for "imagecreatefrombmp") and was brought to perfection. Now it covers compressed 4- and 8-bit, ignores unimportant headers and supports the special 16-bit 565 mask as well.

Comment: New URL: https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/blob/master/src/Helpers.php#L555

Answer (score 0):

How about the [imagejpeg](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php) function?

> bool imagejpeg  ( resource $image  [,
>   string $filename  [, int $quality  ]]
>   )
>
> imagejpeg() creates a JPEG file from
>   the given image .

For help to support BMP format in GD, have a look [here](http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/3033-there-bmp-support-gd), for example.

EDIT: This doesn't support 16 bit images which is correct as the original bitmap specification doesn't support it. In your case, please find out which bit pattern is used to code the color value. I assume it's 5 bits for R and B, 6 bits for G and the order is BGR in this solution (please insert into the code I linked to above):

```
else if ($bits == 16) {
$gd_scan_line = "";
$j = 0;
while($j < $scan_line_size) {
$byte1 = $scan_line{$j++};
$byte2 = $scan_line{$j++};
$b = chr($byte1 >> 3) * (255 / 31); 
$g = (chr($byte1 & 0x07) + chr($byte2 >> 5)) * (255 / 63);
$r = chr($byte2 & 0x1F) * (255 / 31);
$gd_scan_line .= "\x00$r$g$b";
}
```

Note that I didn't test this code (specifically, I'm not sure about that scaling to 0..255) and it will only work if 5-6-5 bit pattern has been used (well, it will work with others, too, but the colors will be wrong).

Comment: Thank you for a quick reply but I keep running into the same problem.  The bitmap files that my client is using are 16-bit bitmap files.  EVERY implementation that I have found (including the one you have shown) account for 24-bit, 8-bit, 4-bit and 1-bit bitmaps.

Comment: Thank you again.  I tried this solution.  The resulting file that was returned was a solid black image with horizontal green lines spaced equally apart the entire length of the image.

Answer (score 0):

While GD does not support BMP natively, a little big of googling provides a [few](http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/3033-there-bmp-support-gd#post10611) [userland](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreate.php#53879) [implementations](http://www.phpro.org/examples/Convert-BMP-to-JPG.html) of a imagecreatefrombmp() function.

I haven't tried them, but I'm confident at least one of them will work for you.

Comment: Thanks again.  I have tried them all.  Again when I do some testing I find out the the bitmaps that are being submitted are 16-bit files.  16-bit images are not accounted for in any of these implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head:

```
function convert_to_jpeg( $input_path, $output_path )
{
    $image = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($input_path));
    imagejpeg($image, $output_path);
    imagedestroy($image);
}
```

That'll take any format GD can handle as input, and output a jpeg file. I don't know what version of GD you folks are using, but mine handles .bmp perfectly and so did the version we used at the previous company I worked for. (on Mac OS X 10.6 and CentOS 5 respectively)

**edit**: forgot imagedestroy! ouch!

Comment: Let's hope that works for 16-bit BMP files, too... would be the quickest and most elegant solution.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I gave this a try and got this error:

imagecreatefromstring() [function.imagecreatefromstring]: Data is not in a recognized format.

This is probably due to the darn 16-bit bitmaps that my client is using.

Comment: I don't think I ever ran into a 16bit image, but it seems to work fine for 24bits, and even RLE encoded images.